# How can I manually add another model to view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, viewmodel

When i created view called Products i specified model Product for it  trough view generator window and i used that model to show products from database

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-column productbox">
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.ProductImg)" class="img-responsive" >
            <div class="producttitle">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</div>
            <div class="producttitle">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDesc)</div>
            <div class="productprice"><div class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">BUY</a></div><div class="pricetext">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductPrice)</div></div>
        </div>

    }
```

now i want to generate list of categories from database on same view as actionlinks so when user clicks, it show products from that category ...something like this

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName).ToString(),"Products",new { controller="Home",action="Products",id=modelItem=>item.CategoryID})
    </li>

}
    </ul>
</div>
```

but i need to include somehow model of Category in view like this is included for Product

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineProdajaSlika.Models.Product>
```

i am mvc newbie and cant figure it out ,any help is appreciated

Comment: Create a new "composite model" that includes all you need, both `Product` and a list of `Category`.

Comment: so its not possible to include other model in that view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is a view model that has one or more properties, something like:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    // Property to hold your products
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

    // Property to hold the category details
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can populate these details within your controller action and return this model:

```
public MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ProductsPage()
    {
        var viewModel = new ProductsViewModel
        {
            Products = new List<Product>(),
            Categories = new List<Category>()
        };

        // Populate the products
        viewModel.Products.Add(new Product { ProductName = "Product 1" });
        viewModel.Products.Add(new Product { ProductName = "Product 2" });

        // Populate the categories on the same view model
        viewModel.Categories.Add(new Category { CategoryName = "Category 1" });
        viewModel.Categories.Add(new Category { CategoryName = "Category 2" });

        // Return the view model with all of the details
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Then define this view model in your view and loop your data:

```
@model ProductsViewModel

@* Loop the products in the model *@
@foreach(var product in Model.Products)
{
    <div>@product.ProductName</div>
}

@* Loop the categories in the model *@
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{
    <div>@category.CategoryName</div>
}
```

Comment: so now i delete my old separate classes Product and Category and do it the right way u show me ? btw thank you a lot for answer its amazing

Comment: You can only have 1 model per view or partial view, so you'll have to do it this way. Glad to be of service :) good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new view model specific for this view.

```
public class ProductsAndCategoriesVm
{
  public IEnumerable<Product> Products {set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<Category> Categories {set;get;}
  public ProductsAndCategoriesVm()
  {
    Products = new List<Product>();
    Categories = new List<Category>();
  }
}
```

and in your GET Action, create an object of this, assign both the property values and send it to the view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm = new ProductsAndCategoriesVm();
  // Set vm.Products
  //  vm.Products=dbContext.Products.ToList();
  // Set vm.Categories
  //  vm.Categories=dbContext.Categories.ToList();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now your view should be strongly typed to this view model

```
@model ProductsAndCategoriesVm
<h1>Products</h1>
@foreach(var p in Model.Products)
{
  <p>@p.ProductName</p>
}
<h1>Categories </h1>
@foreach(var c in Model.Categories)
{
  <p>@Html.ActionLink(c.CategoryName,"Products","Home",new { @id=c.CategoryID},null)</p>
}
```